# Can't access apache webserver remotely after connecting to VPN

Tags: vpn, bash, linux-networking

I have an apache webserver installed on my pc whcih works as expected untill I connect to my VPN service provider (Private Internet Access) using their software.

Once connected I'm no longer able to remotely access the webserver (using my ISP's public ip address `123.4.5.6`) with `Connection Timeout` error every time I try to access it. However the webserver will remain reachable through my local area network (using LAN ip address `192.168.0.6`).

Here's my network diagram to the best of my knowledge (the isp and vpn ips are not the real ones):

[image: Network Diagram]

Here's some info I gathered about the network (I disabled my `UFW` firewall and flushed all `iptables` rules to rule out the possibility that the firewall is causing it):

**Before connecting to VPN:**

```
me@mypc:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0


me@mypc:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:09:b4:b9:21  
          inet addr:192.168.0.6  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21d:9ff:feb4:b921/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:239399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:89260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:321072109 (321.0 MB)  TX bytes:17959636 (17.9 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:359782 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:359782 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:140030332 (140.0 MB)  TX bytes:140030332 (140.0 MB)UU
```

**After connecting to VPN:**

```
me@mypc:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.132.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.132.1.1      10.132.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.132.1.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.132.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
234.5.6.7       192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0


me@mypc:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:09:b4:b9:21  
          inet addr:192.168.0.6  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:238838 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:88929 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:320930349 (320.9 MB)  TX bytes:17868326 (17.8 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:348572 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:348572 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:135702614 (135.7 MB)  TX bytes:135702614 (135.7 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.132.1.6  P-t-P:10.132.1.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:833 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:694943 (694.9 KB)  TX bytes:105489 (105.4 KB)
```

What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add route to 123.4.5.6 trought your ISP gate.
For example:

```
route add -host 123.4.5.6 gw 192.168.0.1
```

According your Linux distribution put this rule for routing  in appropriate config file.

Comment: It worked like magic :))) could you please explain to me what was the problem and how did this fix it? In my understanding I think that the incoming http requests are forwarded from the router to the webserver so why should i forward the requests back to the router (I guess that's what the rule u mentioned does?). thanks

Comment: Sounds great. OK. Let me explain. You are completely right for incoming traffic. But for outgoing traffic web server put http packets through vpn. Your computer doesn't know how to reach ip 123.4.5.6 and for this reason it use default gateway from your VPN. When we add above route we say reach this ip trought this gateway not use dafault gateway and vpn. This is rule will be active until restart. My idea is to add this rule in config faile to make it permanent.

Comment: perfect, that's explained everything, thanks you very much.

Comment: Turns out It's not working as I expected, I'm only able to access the webserver from my local network (using my router ip address 123.4.5.6), If i try to connect from another ip address it times out. How can I forward all http packets properly? I tried to add some `iptables` rules but didn't work please help.

Comment: Do you have access from external addresses to web server when vpn is shut down?

Comment: Try configure manual routing tables. You have to change default gateway from  10.132.1.5  to  192.168.0.1. and add route for network 10.132.1.0/24 trought vpn.

Comment: How do I do that?